# Can IIS and SQL run on the same Azure Virtual Machine?

Tags: sql, iis, azure

I am testing moving our websites to Azure.

I have created an Azure virtual machine and Installed IIS and SQL on it.

Following that I have uploaded the website (MVC Framework 4.5) to IIS. Having created a temporary index.htm file (for testing) I can access it externally using the relevant URL.

I have also created the SQL database and can connect to it externally.

However when I try to access the original recreated website (which should connect to the SQL database) I get the standard error below:

"500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed."

I have tried all permutations of the connection string (using the correct username and password) to but no avail.

Can IIS and SQL be running on the same VM and if so, what is missing so as to be able to allow the Website to connect to SQL?

I have done all the Googling I can think of so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: No idea what your issue is, but... If you're running Windows Server, then you can run whatever you want that would normally run on Windows Server. Relatively no difference vs on-premises servers, aside from accessibility to hardware.

Comment: Thanks David, this is what I thought, so I am stumped as to why it would not connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Said I would get back to this question. Solution was to copy relevant System.Web.* MVC files to the server. The first connection string above worked.

Answer (score 4):

You can definitely run IIS and SQL on the same machine. Hard to guess what is wrong without seeing the whole error or code however sqlcmd could help in troubleshooting. You can use this to verify that you are able to connect.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx

Comment: Thanks Casey for your suggestion. Good to know that the setup of IIS and SQL on the same VM is not a problem. Tested using sqlcmd and can connect with the webuser for the application. What other information can I supply that would be useful?

Comment: Your connection string would be very helpful

Comment: Below are two connection strings. The first is the orginal one and the second the current one. Neither have worked:

Comment: <add name="AppContext" connectionString="Data Source=SQL2012;Initial Catalog=DBName;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=AppUser;Password=AppUserPassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: <add name="AppContext" connectionString="Data Source=tcp:10.1.0.4\SQL2012,1433;Initial Catalog=DBName;User ID=AppUser;Password=AppUserPassword;Encrypt=true;Trusted_Connection=false;TrustServerCertificate=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

Comment: <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=MACHINENAME\SERVER;Initial Catalog=DATABASE;User Id=USER;Password=PASSWORD;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: Try that out and see how it works, if not try to give us some more information on the errors if you are having troubles seeing the error then add this to your web.config     
    
    <customErrors mode="Off" />

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Casey. I am going to create a new trial account to do a fresh installation. The previous account I tested a number of scenarios in and so not sure if that may have created an issue. I will put this question on hold until the new setup is done. Nonetheless, will definitely revisit this question to provide feedback on the new installation, be it good or bad. Thanks for your input.